# rails 3 css specific for controller is not loading in production (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

i built a small rails application and pushed it to heroku. 
everything seem to be working fine. except the styling i gave to views through the sepcific file css generated for each controller. in: app/assests/stylesheets for example:

```
main.css.scss
```

which has this code in it:

```
.login_form {max-width:455px;}
```

is not loading in view in my

```
main_controller
```

only application.css is loading
what do i need to configure?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that you need to precompile your assets.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

Read up on the [Rails Guides Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

That would explain why it worked in development, but the production environment is set to expect to use precompiled assets.